# Thread-scoped objects in C++11 with GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

Consider the following C++11 program:

```
struct S {
   S() {/* do something */ }
} global_object;

int main() {
}
```

I don't have `GCC 4.8` yet to test, but from what I read about the C++11 standard, no matter if I declare the global object as `thread_local`, the object itself will be instantiated once for all the possible threads that can be created during the execution of the program.

Is there a way (portable or not) in GCC to have the global object instantiated and constrcuted every time one thread starts and destructed every time the same thread finishes?

Comment: @AndyProwl I have made the question more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *but from what I read about the C++11 standard, no matter if I declare the global object as `thread_local`, the object itself will be instantiated once for all the possible threads that can be created during the execution of the program.*

This is not what the C++11 standard states. The relevant sections from C++11 standard (draft n3337):

- *3.7.2 Thread storage duration*, clause 1:

> All variables declared with the `thread_local` keyword have thread storage duration. The storage for these entities shall last for the duration of the thread in which they are created. **There is a distinct object or reference per thread**, and use of the declared name refers to the entity associated with the current thread.

- *7.1.1 Storage class specifiers*, clause 4:

> The `thread_local` specifier indicates that the named entity has thread storage duration (3.7.2). **It shall be applied only to the names of variables of namespace or block scope and to the names of static data members.**  When thread_local is applied to a variable of block scope the storage-class-specifier static is implied if it does not appear explicitly.

Nowhere does it state that if an object is defined in the global namespace with `thread_local` that only a single instance of it will be created. An alternative example to that already posted by [Jesse Good](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906773/jesse-good) prints the *unique* address of each instance of the global object (see [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b7d59e596d40b551abf042bb7681a877-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct S {};
thread_local S global_s;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread([](){ std::cout << &global_s << '\n'; }));
    for (auto& t: threads) t.join();
}
```

Output:

```
0x4165993f
0x4205a93f
0x4485e93f
0x42a5b93f
0x4525f93f
0x45c6093f
0x4666193f
0x4706293f
0x43e5d93f
0x4345c93f
```

Answer (score 3):

> no matter if I declare the global object as thread_local

Did you try it out? I'm pretty sure that it *will* create a separate instance per thread.

See the following code on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=40cd338821d53bc35c526ca16dadd699-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51):

```
struct S {
   int i = 0;
   S() {}
};

thread_local S global;

int main()
{
    std::thread t1([](){global.i = 1; std::cout << global.i << std::endl;});
    t1.join();
    std::cout << global.i << std::endl;
    std::thread t2([](){global.i = 2; std::cout << global.i << std::endl;});
    t2.join();
    std::cout << global.i << std::endl;
    std::thread t3([](){global.i = 3; std::cout << global.i << std::endl;});
    t3.join();
    std::cout << global.i << std::endl;
}
```

It outputs:

```
1
0
2
0
3
0
```

Comment: In your example, I think you should `join` _before_ `cout`ing the base thread's value. Just for sanity.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yeah, the synchronization was a bit off. Fixed, thanks.